# Ubuntu 14.04 Server: How to switch to installed gui

Tags: 14.04, server, gui, tty

I've installed a minimal gnome desktop on my ubuntu 14.04 server. How do I switch to it? Right now i'm on the tty. I tried `Alt+f7` but it just takes me to a screen with a red cursor flashing in the top left corner. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is type the command:

```
startx
```

from a command prompt (tty1-tty6).

Your Xsession should start on tty7, although, it may start on tty8 or another.

Comment: @mdpc it doesn't just depend on system configuration and can also depend on other factors, such as, if tty7 or tty8 are already in use.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you call "minimal", do:

```
cp /etc/skel/.xinitrc ~
echo 'exec gnome-session' >> ~/.xinitrc
startx ~/.xinitrc gnome-session
```

using [`.xinitrc`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc) to start X.
Or:

```
service start gdm
```

(if you installed `gdm`, or other Display Managers, such as `lightdm`).